# Queue 10 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms

Tags: networking, drivers, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS a few days and started having issues with the wifi adapter (intel dual band wireless ac-3160), where it would randomly stop working after some point of time (sometimes immediately after boot, sometimes hours after startup) and required a restart before it would work again. Looking through dmesg for clues as to what is going on, I saw

```
Queue 10 is active on fifo 2 and stuck for 10000 ms. SW [3, 19] HW [90, 90] FH TRB=0x05a5a5a5a
```

I'm not sure what's going on here but I've done some searching online and among the solutions i found (turn off power management, use an older kernel, update firmware, disable bluetooth, etc) none of them seem to work. I really want to keep using Ubuntu since it's so much more convenient to complete schoolwork with it rather than Windows but if I cannot fix this intermittent issue then I will have to go back to Windows :/

Comment: Please run after the wireless is stuck: `dmesg | grep iwl` As the result will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555  Hi there,

Here's the output from `dmesg | grep iwl`
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3bhzQVXYSW/

it seems to be happening on/right after bootup now.

Comment: Is this a dual boot with Windows? Does the device work as expected in Windows? Is there any difference between a cold boot and a reboot?

Comment: It's not a dual boot, only Ubuntu right now. The device did work previously under Windows. No difference between reboot and cold bootup...

Answer (score 0):

In your dmesg, we see these alarming lines:

```
[   47.424641] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
[   47.424688] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Error sending SCAN_OFFLOAD_REQUEST_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
[   47.424694] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Scan failed! ret -5
[   48.109479] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: iwlwifi transaction failed, dumping registers
```

A search suggests a possible fix. Reference: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=240916

> try "net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0" (either a kernel parameter or via sysctl)

Let’s add this as a boot parameter and see if performance improves. From the terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change it to this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash net.ipv4.tcp_ecn=0"
```

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit nano (Ctrl+x).

Now do:

```
sudo update grub
```

Reboot and paste, as above:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

And give us the link.

Comment: Hi again, sorry for the late reply. I've tried the fix you suggested, and it worked okay for a few hours, and then suddenly it stopped working again. Here's the output from `dmesg | grep iwl` again https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mcdNvMJrSz/

Comment: Is the firmware file corrupted? Please check: `md5sum /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode` We hope you get fee0d7dddf8437148ab25c4b1a34202c. Does it restart if you do: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` Is it at all possible that the hardware is defective?

Comment: `md5sum /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-17.ucode` does indeed give me fee0d7dddf8437148ab25c4b1a34202c. Running `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi` disables and renables the card as expected... as for defective hardware, I suppose that is always a possibility, although I'm not sure how to check for that. The card worked under Windows; I guess if there is some sort of defect with the hardware then it either doesn't bother Windows or Windows is able to work despite it...